# Pandas Groupby Aggregate Return Customized Output (not one row)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in the following format

```
| col1 | col2  | 
|  1   |  day1 |
|  1   |  day2 |
|  1   |  day3 |
|  2   |  day1 | 
|  2   |  day3 |
```

I have a pretty customized logic/function that works on a single dataframe for one value of col1 that I will like to apply to all values. It is sort of the groupby. However, I seem not to get the aggregate part right, as to me it looks like only return 1 value, (like max/min/count/..). What if my aggregate function return a dataframe and have more than 1 rows?

For example, the expected output could be

```
| col1 | col2       | 
|  1   |  day1-day2 |
|  1   |  day2-day3 |
|  2   |  day1-day3 |
```

As you can tell, there are two rows generated out of group1 and one row out of group2. And the aggregation logic is every two consecutive rows concatenation, or even more complex. It is sort of the map reduce idea in Spark/Hadoop but couldn't get it working in group.aggregate...

Update:

people usually do groupby().agg(sum), it works as sum return 1 row or 1 number. However, I have a function that return a dataframe which could be 0,1 or many rows, it reduce the number of rows for sure but not quite as collapsing to 1 row yet, like groupby().agg(func), is it possible to do this in groupby.agg?

```
def func(xdf):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(xdf)-1):
        res.append(xdf.iloc[i] + '-' + xdf.iloc[i+1])
    return pd.DataFrame(res) # return a dataframe, not a number, not a row.
```

Comment: there are different way of approaching this in distributed tech  Spark v/s a 1 core tech like pandas. pandas needs `rolling `may be based on your output with `join` for pyspark it depends drastically because partitions are involved so we need a more clear example of what you are trying to do here.. :) friendly advice is to narrow down to the most relevant mcve you can..

Comment: @anky, I have provided the sample input, sampleout, is there anything else you think can help clarify (it is tagged as a pandas question)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. if you change `agg` by `apply`, it works as expected. try `df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(func)` :) you'll just need some cosmetic to make it looks like what you want

Comment: @Ben.T, ah! apply is exactly what I am looking for, if you want to post a sample answer, I will accept. Thanks Ben.

Comment: Agreed with @Ben.T apply would be useful here, its a good Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `groupby.agg`, you can use `groupby.apply`, like this with your data and function `func`, you get

```
print (df.groupby('col1').apply(func))
             col2
col1             
1    0  day1-day2
     1  day2-day3
2    0  day1-day3
```

and for getting the expected output format, you can use `reset_index` as well

```
print (df.groupby('col1').apply(func)
         .reset_index(level=0)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
   col1       col2
0     1  day1-day2
1     1  day2-day3
2     2  day1-day3
```

​but in your real case, you might not need it

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you to where you want.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
'col2': ['  day1 ', '  day2 ', '  day3 ', '  day1 ', '  day3 '],
'col3': ['  day1 ', '  day2 ', '  day3 ', '  day1 ', '  day3 ']})
```

Groupby each column

```
gb = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).nth(0)
```

Then groupby again and dropna's

```
gb.groupby(['col1']).shift(-1).dropna()
```

Which yields

```
col1    col2    col3
1     day1    day2 
1     day2    day3 
2     day1    day3
```

Comment: The question is more like a question of how to return multiple rows within a group, and I used an example to illustrate the idea, your shift(-1) is indeed brilliant but not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: So multiple rows do you mean like the groupby and then .nth([0, 1])?

Comment: I updaded my question a bit to illustrate the idea, func could be any customized function and frankly speaking, the outcome could be any free form of dataframe.